# Check if POSIXct has a time associated with it or NOT

Tags: r

```
str(datetime)
POSIXct[1:250000], format: "1999-05-28 07:30:00" "1999-05-28 08:00:00" "1999-05-28 08:30:00" "1999-05-28 09:00:00" "1999-05-28 09:30:00" ...

str(secondset2)
POSIXct[1:7821], format: "1993-04-28" "1993-04-29" "1993-04-30" "1993-05-03" "1993-05-04" "1993-05-05" "1993-05-06" "1993-05-07" "1993-05-10" "1993-05-11" ...
```

I have 2 POSIXct variables, how do i detect if one has a time associated with it and if one does not. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I tried this but I dont think this is correct..
if(is.na(datetime)){}
if(!is.na(datetime)){}

Comment: All POSIXct have a time associated with them. If the times are all midnight (00:00:00), they print as YYYY-MM-DD however. Compare `as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00")` vs. `as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:01")`. See `format.POSIXlt` and near the end you'll notice the formats printed out change depending on whether there are non-midnight times, or milliseconds stored.

Comment: If the question remains how to identify those with midnight times, maybe `trunc(x, units="days") == x` ? Or `all(trunc(x, units="days") == x)` ? Let me know if that matches what you need.

Comment: Whether it is at midnight or not also depends on the time zone.

Comment: I'm trying to compare datasets of times where if one data set has midnight times.. perform this action is another data set does not have midnight times perform a different action. I was looking to accomplish this using if statements